# Error "class path contains multiple slf4J bindings" when opening newly installed HDFViewer on windows 10

Tags: hdf5, hdf, f5

I have problem opening HDFViewer on win10. 
I installed HDFView-3.1.2-win10_64-vs16.zip from this link: [enter link description here](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/),
 Visual C++ Redistributable Packages from this link: [enter link description here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) 
 and have added HDFViewer to environmental variables. "USERPATH\AppData\Local\HDF_Group\HDFView\runtime\bin" 
 " At the end, restarted windows; however, I still get the same error message which shows 1 seconds and disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says what the problem is: The loader found 3 candidates for log output handlers. You need to find a way to remove 2 of them from the load path.

The `.jar` files with `nop` in the name are no-ops, that is, they are stubs that accept method calls to log output, but they do not cause any output. The file with `simple` in its name actually generates log output.

Any one of these files being present would fulfill the requirement for a logger endpoint. The loader does not know which to choose and so sits on its virtual hands and pouts.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
I deleted the 1st and 3rd ones. The mentioned error was solved. But Now, this message appears and still no success to open the app. 
Isn't there any log I can see more detail on this cause it disappear so fast that I can hardly take snapshot: 
[main] INFO hdf.view.HDFView - Current directory is C:\Users\Simin
[main] INFO hdf.view.HDFView - Menubar created

Comment: I am glad to have helped you solve your problem. Please accept my answer and upvote it.

You do not say what the new error is. Two further suggestions: 1) Look at the source code, especially the startup part. 2) Use a debugger to set a breakpoint, and step through the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned error was solved using @mike Slinn solution. But Now, this message appears and still no success to open the app. 
 Isn't there any log I can see more detail on this cause it disappear so fast that I can hardly take snapshot 
[image]